# XMPP iOS: unable to connect openfire server

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xmpp

I develop the iOS XMPP app with the tutorial in this link >>> http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-setup--mobile-7190

And now I run my project it is not connecting to my openfire server but there are no errors displaying. I heard some developers they had solve relevant problem by "enabling" SSL certificate in iOS client in this link >>> [Unable to connect openfire server using ios client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591553/unable-to-connect-openfire-server-using-ios-client/25061900?noredirect=1#comment38988394_25061900). Do I have to enable it? and how to enable it?

This problem had takes me a week so I decided to post on stackoverflow.

here is my "JabberClientAppDelegate.m"

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  JabberClient
//
//  Created by Lance on 7/30/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Lance. All rights reserved.
//

#import "JabberClientAppDelegate.h"

#import "SMBuddyListViewController.h"

@interface JabberClientAppDelegate()

- (void)setupStream;
- (void)goOnline;
- (void)goOffline;

@end

@implementation JabberClientAppDelegate

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize chatDelegate;
@synthesize messageDelegate;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    SMBuddyListViewController *masterViewController = [[SMBuddyListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SMBuddyListViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.viewController = masterViewController;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender {

    // connection to the server successful
    isOpen = YES;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:password error:&error];

}

- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender {

    // authentication successful
    [self goOnline];
}


- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message {

    // message received
    NSString *msg = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
    NSString *from = [[message attributeForName:@"from"] stringValue];

    NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [m setObject:msg forKey:@"msg"];
    [m setObject:from forKey:@"sender"];

    [_messageDelegate newMessageReceived:m];

}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence {

    NSString *presenceType = [presence type]; // online/offline
    NSString *myUsername = [[sender myJID] user];
    NSString *presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];

    if (![presenceFromUser isEqualToString:myUsername]) {

        if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"available"]) {

            [_chatDelegate newBuddyOnline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", presenceFromUser, @"localhost"]];

        } else if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"unavailable"]) {

            [_chatDelegate buddyWentOffline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", presenceFromUser, @"localhost"]];

        }

    }
}

- (void)setupStream {
    xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
    [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [self disconnect];

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [xmppStream setHostName:@"localhost"];
    [xmppStream setHostPort:5222];
}

- (void)goOnline {
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
}

- (void)goOffline {
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"unavailable"];
    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
}

- (BOOL)connect {

    [self setupStream];

    NSString *jabberID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userID"];
    NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userPassword"];

    if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
        return YES;
    }

    if (jabberID == nil || myPassword == nil) {

        return NO;
    }

    [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:jabberID]];
    password = myPassword;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error]){
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't connect to server %@", nil]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

        return NO;
    }

    if(![xmppStream isConnected]){
        NSLog(@"connected");
    }
    //[[self xmppStream] authenticateAnonymously:&error];
    [self xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:xmppStream];
    return YES;
}

- (void)disconnect {

    [self goOffline];
    [xmppStream disconnect];

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}



- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}

- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"JabberClient" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"JabberClient.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

         If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
         * Simply deleting the existing store:
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

         * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter:
         @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}

         Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end
```

I am sorry if there are too much codes to review, I am a beginner of iOS development and XMPP, please kindly review my mistake and guide me how to fix I'll be truly appreciate, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to set port number and host name of server.

Try this.

```
- (BOOL)connect {

        [self setupStream];

    // set openfire server host name and port number to connect 
    [self.xmppStream setHostName:@"serverHostName"];
    [self.xmppStream setHostPort:@"serverPortNumber"];

        NSString *jabberID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userID"];
        NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userPassword"];

        if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
            return YES;
        }

        if (jabberID == nil || myPassword == nil) {

            return NO;
        }


        [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:jabberID]];
        password = myPassword;

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error]){
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't connect to server %@", nil]
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];

            return NO;
        }



        return YES;
    }
```